# How to Import Webview data into the listview

Tags: android

I am getting a list of numbers in the webview from server. I want to import these numbers into the listview. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting a list of numbers in the webview from server. I want to
>   import these numbers into the listview

*Not possible to extract data from WebView*

You should use `HttpURLConnection` to get data from page and some thired party library for parsing HTML like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)